# How can I build a small DC boost converter, similar to what exists on a flash camera circuit board?

Tags: oscillator, camera, flash

So everyone knows that disposable camera flash boards have a small DC boost converter to power the tiny xenon flash tube.  I have read several sources on the internet that seem to suggest that the board does this in 2 steps:

1) 1.5V DC is converted to an AC wave through a small oscillator circuit, fed through the small transformer (larger of the 2 on a typical board), which boosts the source to 250-300V, and is stored in the notorious large capacitor.

2) When the flash switch is closed, the capacitor discharges, and it is again stepped up through a smaller trigger coil, jumping it to over 1000V to turn on the xenon.

My question is, how can I build the first section of the circuit with discrete components on a breadboard?  I am not sure of how the circuit works, how the oscillator works, and more and sadly many websites out there fail miserably at explaining it.

Comment: be very careful with the voltages you are aiming at. It is a fun project but high voltages can be lethal too. Make sure you have check with a voltmeter before touching things.

Comment: You need to specify the current after the first step. That will determine how flash the charges.

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start understanding and designing a boost converter would be by playing with one of the various online power design tools published by part manufacturers, such as:

- Fairchild Semiconductor: [Power Supply WebDesigner](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/design_tools/power-supply-webdesigner/)
- Linear Technology: [LTPowerCAD](http://video.linear.com/30)
- Texas Instruments: [WeBench Power Designer](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/analog/webench/power.shtml), [SwitcherPro Design Tool](http://www.ti.com/tool/switcherpro)

Many of these tools go as far as providing a schematic, a bill of materials,  performance parametrics and in some cases even design simulation, all for free.

Once you have some idea of what works and what doesn't, why, and how, you would have to start either narrowing your design down to use through-hole parts for the breadboard (not many boost controllers are produced in through-hole packages), or putting together little breakouts for SMD parts.

For the breakouts, consider using the appropriate [Schmartboard SMT to DIP adapters](http://www.schmartboard.com/index.asp?page=products_smttodip), or less finely engineered, much cheaper and yet usable little DIP adapter PCBs from sites like eBay:

[image: SMD to DIP] *(from [this listing](http://www.ebay.com/itm/SOP-20-to-DIP-20-pin-Adapter-PCB-SMD-SOP-SOP20-Convert-Free-Shipping-/170878878998?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27c92cc516))*

---

Important factors to keep in mind when prototyping on breadboard:

- You will not be able to operate at high switching frequencies for the boost convertor, due to the stray capacitances and inductances of a breadboard, contact resistance, and the high effective trace distances a 0.1" pitch breadboard will force upon you.
- Efficiency will not be anywhere close to advertised figures for the specific parts you choose for your design.
- Decoupling is a huge challenge with a breadboard

  - Every attempt I have made at breadboarding a boost converter has resulted in frequent random spikes and dips in output.
- Often boost controller ICs have specific layout requirements, especially for thermal pads for cooling, and you are probably not going to get anywhere with meeting those requirements with generic DIP adapter PCBs.

Good luck, and do update your question to share how you get along.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doind this for learn&fun — try building [simple impulse generator with a 555](http://www.csgnetwork.com/ne555timer2calc.html). Then take that impulses to the gate pin of MOSFET and drive a suitable  transformer. Rectify transformer's output and charge a high-voltage capacitor with a resulting voltage.
Something like that:
[image: 555 high voltage generator(NOT TESTED)]

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I've built myself a Nixie clock once and I used a MC34063 DC-DC Boost Converter.
A design tool is available here:
http://www.nomad.ee/micros/mc34063a/

Worked like charm to convert 13V up to 170V.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Input drives a chip to create a 20KHz or so square wave to a step transformer and half rectifier with dual diodes for extra PIV protection.  Once a DC threshold is reached the indicator light signal left is ON and once the manual flash button is pressed top right, the IGBT Q1 (read .. really high Vce breakdown voltage  NPN  switch) switches the Perkin Elmer zenon tube (FT1) to ground while at the same time triggering the center terminal by grounding C3 to inject a current pulse via T2. Once the tube fires it bridges the tube to discharge the power from C2 , the low ESR Cap that stores your kila-Joules of charge. The power and ground loop between C2 , FT1 and Q1 must be tiny for EMI reasons. A total ESR of the loop ought to be in the 100 mΩ ~1Ω range for track inductance, C3 and Q1. Lower the better as long as within FT tube specs.

For more details http://cds.linear.com/docs/Demo%20Board%20Manual/dc855A.pdf